# java 17, the ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField does not work on a final field

Tags: android, unit-testing, reflection

Android project's unit test, which needs to test with different `BuildConfig.DEBUG` value

The BuildConfig class has DEBUG as final

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
}
```

This code works fine until update to java 17

```
ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(BuildConfig.class, "DEBUG", true);
```

With java 17, now it gets error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set the value of final field public static final boolean com.oath.mobile.shadowfax.adm.BuildConfig.DEBUG
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
```

I think for the test case we can modify the code to use a function for the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` value. But ingeneral is there alternative to do modify a final field of a class?